# Running Pow on GIT repo branch

Tags: ruby, git, rack-pow

I've checked out my Ruby project from GIT and I've installed [pow](http://pow.cx) to run it on a friendly URL from my browser.

We've got a stable working version of our app running in our GIT 'master', but now I want to run our development branch on the same pow URL. I've already switched the working branch to our development branch 'redesign', but the Pow URL is complaining with error in the screen.

My question: Is it even possible to run POW on a directory using a GIT branch other than 'master'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you might need to restart pow to force it to refresh the code.

There's two ways to do this:

- `touch ~/.pow/restart.txt`
- Install the `powder` gem. That allows you to run `powder restart` on your app directory.

Also, you might want to run `bundle` on your project directory too, as dependencies might have changed in the new branch (hard to tell without more information.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @changelog. That seemed to work just fine. Also saves restarting the app.